# Unable to (force) import zpool after disk replace (I/O error)

Tags: linux, import, zfs

I have difficulties importing my raidz1-0 array after replacing a broken disk. I was unable to 'offline' the broken disk before the disk swap and now I cannot import the zpool anymore in order to 'replace' the broken disk.

I do not have a backup/export and I am getting worried. As only one disk faulted i hope(d) that I would be able to recover the pool but I cannot think of anything else to try. Any advise/tips/suggestions are very welcome!

See below the steps I followed.

> System: Linux nas 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.57-3 x86_64
>   GNU/Linux
>
> **root@nas:/home/lucas# zpool status -v**
>
> > no pools available
>
> **root@nas:/home/lucas# zpool import**

```
   pool: naspool
     id: 3030059305965279629
  state: DEGRADED
 status: One or more devices contains corrupted data.
 action: The pool can be imported despite missing or damaged devices.  The
        fault tolerance of the pool may be compromised if imported.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-4J
 config:

        naspool                                 DEGRADED
          raidz1-0                              DEGRADED
            sda                                 ONLINE
            scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-1CH_Z1F3LC75  ONLINE
            ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_Z1F0QJHV     ONLINE
            sdd                                 ONLINE
            sde                                 UNAVAIL
```

**root@nas:/home/lucas# zpool import naspool**

> cannot import 'naspool': pool may be in use from other system use '-f'
>   to import anyway

**root@nas:/home/lucas# zpool import naspool -f**

> cannot import 'naspool': I/O error
>           Destroy and re-create the pool from
>           a backup source.

**root@nas:/home/lucas# zdb**

> cannot open '/etc/zfs/zpool.cache': No such file or directory

**root@nas:/home/lucas# ls -l /dev/disk/by-id**

```
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 29 09:23 ata-SanDisk_SDSSDP128G_133230401711 -> ../../sdf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 ata-SanDisk_SDSSDP128G_133230401711-part1 -> ../../sdf1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 ata-SanDisk_SDSSDP128G_133230401711-part2 -> ../../sdf2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 ata-SanDisk_SDSSDP128G_133230401711-part3 -> ../../sdf3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 29 09:23 ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_W1F39CBE -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 29 09:23 ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F3LC75 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F3LC75-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 ata-ST3000DM001-1CH166_Z1F3LC75-part9 -> ../../sdb9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 29 09:23 ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_Z1F0PXHP -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_Z1F0PXHP-part1 -> ../../sdd1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_Z1F0PXHP-part9 -> ../../sdd9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 29 09:23 ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_Z1F0QJHV -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_Z1F0QJHV-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_Z1F0QJHV-part9 -> ../../sdc9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 29 09:23 ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_Z1F0RGWW -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_Z1F0RGWW-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_Z1F0RGWW-part9 -> ../../sda9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 29 09:23 scsi-SATA_SanDisk_SDSSDP1133230401711 -> ../../sdf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 scsi-SATA_SanDisk_SDSSDP1133230401711-part1 -> ../../sdf1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 scsi-SATA_SanDisk_SDSSDP1133230401711-part2 -> ../../sdf2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 scsi-SATA_SanDisk_SDSSDP1133230401711-part3 -> ../../sdf3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 29 09:23 scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-1CH_W1F39CBE -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 29 09:23 scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-1CH_Z1F3LC75 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-1CH_Z1F3LC75-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-1CH_Z1F3LC75-part9 -> ../../sdb9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 29 09:23 scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F0PXHP -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F0PXHP-part1 -> ../../sdd1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F0PXHP-part9 -> ../../sdd9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 29 09:23 scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F0QJHV -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F0QJHV-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F0QJHV-part9 -> ../../sdc9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 29 09:23 scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F0RGWW -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F0RGWW-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-9YN_Z1F0RGWW-part9 -> ../../sda9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 29 09:23 wwn-0x5000c5004d865cbb -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 wwn-0x5000c5004d865cbb-part1 -> ../../sdd1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 wwn-0x5000c5004d865cbb-part9 -> ../../sdd9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 29 09:23 wwn-0x5000c5004d9b492d -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 wwn-0x5000c5004d9b492d-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 wwn-0x5000c5004d9b492d-part9 -> ../../sdc9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 29 09:23 wwn-0x5000c5004d9c3fa6 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 wwn-0x5000c5004d9c3fa6-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 wwn-0x5000c5004d9c3fa6-part9 -> ../../sda9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 29 09:23 wwn-0x5000c500646bb32a -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 wwn-0x5000c500646bb32a-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 wwn-0x5000c500646bb32a-part9 -> ../../sdb9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 29 09:23 wwn-0x5000c50069abed23 -> ../../sde
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Apr 29 09:23 wwn-0x5001b44a10bb94af -> ../../sdf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 wwn-0x5001b44a10bb94af-part1 -> ../../sdf1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 wwn-0x5001b44a10bb94af-part2 -> ../../sdf2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Apr 28 17:30 wwn-0x5001b44a10bb94af-part3 -> ../../sdf3
```

**root@nas:/home/lucas# zpool replace naspool scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-1CH_W1F39CBE**

> cannot open 'naspool': no such pool

**root@nas:/home/lucas# zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id/**

> pool: naspool
>        id: 3030059305965279629   state: DEGRADED  status: One or more devices contains corrupted data.  action: The pool can be imported
>   despite missing or damaged devices.  The
>           fault tolerance of the pool may be compromised if imported.    see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-4J  config:
>
> ```
>     naspool                                 DEGRADED
>       raidz1-0                              DEGRADED
>         ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_Z1F0RGWW     ONLINE
>         scsi-SATA_ST3000DM001-1CH_Z1F3LC75  ONLINE
>         ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_Z1F0QJHV     ONLINE
>         ata-ST3000DM001-9YN166_Z1F0PXHP     ONLINE
>         sde                                 UNAVAIL
> ```

**root@nas:/home/lucas# zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id/ naspool**

> cannot import 'naspool': pool may be in use from other system use '-f'
>   to import anyway

**root@nas:/home/lucas# zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id/ naspool -f**

> cannot import 'naspool': I/O error
>           Destroy and re-create the pool from
>           a backup source.

**root@nas:/home/lucas# zpool import -f -F naspool**

> cannot import 'naspool': I/O error
>           Destroy and re-create the pool from
>           a backup source.

**root@nas:/home/lucas# zpool import -f -F 3030059305965279629**

> cannot import 'naspool': I/O error
>           Destroy and re-create the pool from
>           a backup source.

**root@nas:/home/lucas# zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id/ -f -F 3030059305965279629**

> cannot import 'naspool': I/O error
>           Destroy and re-create the pool from
>           a backup source.

I also tried booting with a zfsGuru live USB stick to import the pool but that did not work:
[image: disk overview, new disk does not contain a label (or partitions)]
[image: zpool is detected]
[image: but importing fails]

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing the information you share, I think the import will not be possible because the image is damaged.